# pytelegrambotapi or

Tags: python, python-3.x, if

Имею такой код(вырезка части):

```
if message.text.startswith('Леха' or 'леха' or 'Лёха' or 'лёха'):
    if ('привет' in message.text):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, hello[r.randint(0, len(hello) - 1)])
```

Функция после if выполняется только если пишу "Леха привет", при этом "Лёха привет" "леха привет" и "лёха привет"- не работают.
Есть решения, или после startswith or не работает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все работает как надо, просто вы не умеете его готовить :)

Попробуйте вывести `print('Леха' or 'леха' or 'Лёха' or 'лёха')` и получите `'Леха'`.

Дело в том, что так работает оператор `or`, а в `startswith` попало одна строка и тот отработал как и задумывалось.

Правильнее было бы использовать `or` так:

```
if message.text.startswith('Леха') or message.text.startswith('леха') or message.text.startswith('Лёха') or message.text.startswith('лёха'):
    ...
```

Согласен, что длинное выражение, но можно укоротить:

```
text = message.text.lower()
if text.startswith('леха') or text.startswith('лёха'):
    ...
```

---

**PS.**

Весь пример:

```
text = message.text.lower()
if (text.startswith('леха') or text.startswith('лёха')) and 'привет' in text:
    my_text = r.choice(hello)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, my_text)
```

Я бы еще упростил этот код:

```
hello[r.randint(0, len(hello) - 1)]
```

`hello` ведь список? Тогда случайный элемент из коллекции можно получить вот так:

```
r.choice(hello)
```

Это явно проще выглядит

Answer (score 1):

Если нравятся регулярки внешний if можно упростить:

```
if re.match(r'л[её]ха', message.text, flags=re.I):
    print(message.text)
```

Comment: можно без `lower`'а, если в `match` передать флаг `re.I` (игнорирование регистра)

Comment: спасибо, сейчас исправлю ответ.